# wpf control in C++/CLI

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, c++-cli

Is it possible to create a WPF control in C++/CLI, like in WinForms? If so, is there a sample/doc somewhere going through the process, since there is no such project type in vs2010.

Thanks

Comment: The primary purpose of C++/CLI is to write .NET wrappers around native C++ code for the purposes of exposing it to other .NET languages. There's basically no use case for writing a .NET control (either WinForms or WPF) in C++/CLI. Just use C#.

Comment: @Cody: There are plenty of use cases for writing a control with C++/CLI.  Maybe you want to wrap a native library, like DirectShow, `IWebBrowser`, or OpenGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you will have to write code to create all your subcontrols and set their properties, because C++/CLI and XAML don't work together.  It's very similar to writing a WinForms UI without the aid of the Forms Designer.

Start just by subclassing one of the WPF controls, perhaps `Panel`.

Comment: A ok, so it wil work. I was thinking it won't work since there is no option for it in the templates. Thanks.